# How to add a .net assembly to the global assembly cache (GAC)

Tags: .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, gac

How to add a libraries to the GAC? Could I lists assembles from GAC in the Visual Studio. I only want to add one file to GAC Library DLL It's AjaxControlToolkit.

Comment: starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an assembly to the GAC using Gacutil.exe.  [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c.aspx). The syntax is:

```
gacutil [options] [assemblyName | assemblyPath | assemblyListFile]
```

You can also use GACUtil.exe to view the contents of the GAC via the command:

```
gacutil –l
```

In versions of Visual Studio prior to 2010, it was possible to use the Assembly Cache Viewer and simply navigate to < System Drive >:\< Windows Folder >\assembly, in Windows Explorer to view the list of assemblies in the GAC.  However, the Assembly Cache Viewer [has been removed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34149zk3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) beginning in .net 4.

Comment: But this don't see my assemblyes after added to Global Assembly Cache. I must add the dll file to the Bin catalog on IIS, and then My Sharepoint see this. I don't know why it's don't see my assembles. Please help.

Comment: You don't see them where?  In the .Net tab on in the "Add Reference" dialog box in visual studio?  Or in the C:\Windows\Assembly folder?

Comment: I see them in Add Reference, and in C:\Windows\Assembly folder. But the program don't see them until add dll fille to the IIS BIN folder..

Answer (score 3):

You can just open the assembly folder (C:\Windows\Assembly), drag and drop the assembly you want...